# Why is website [entire body element] not displaying full width on iOS devices?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, viewport

I have searched a lot of answers to similar questions, but nothing has fixed my issue.

Here is the site: [dev.thekarmagames.com](http://dev.thekarmagames.com)

The width and responsiveness work fine when simulating phone and iPad screens on computer, but something goes wrong when displaying directly in mobile Safari and Chrome on iOS devices.

Here is what it looks like on iOS:

[image: iOS Width Issue Screenshot]

I've tried manipulating CSS, editing/removing JavaScript, and experimenting with viewport settings. Nothing seems to work.

I could really need a lead that will set me in the right direction, and I'll happily share the solution with everyone once I find it.

Comment: your problem is here `.responsive-menu-icon` and this is happening in any mobile view, not just iOS devices.

Comment: That is absolutely it @dippas. Thank you. The .responsive-menu-icon css was too wide and pushing off to right side caused this problem. Setting width property to 30px fixed this issue.